# Django: Is process started from console or from a HTTPRequest?

Tags: python, django, logging

I need to enable logging if a code has been executed from console application (as `manage.py <cmd>`) and to disable logging if HTTPRequest is being processed. Probably filter can be very useful here.

```
LOGGING = {
...
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
           '()': 'IsFromHTTPRequest'
        }
    },
...
}
```

But what is the best way to define if command has been executed or HTTPRequest is being processed? Traceback analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no a good way to do. But here is what we do when we need distinguish `manage.py jenkins` from regular http requests:

Add to settings.py

```
import sys
JENKINS = "jenkins" in sys.argv
```

Then you can use that variable whenever you need. In the log filter as well.